# Pre-setting formControl value alters (breaks) mat-option behavior in mat-select multiple

Tags: angular, angular-material, html-select

**Additional information added at the bottom, 2019DEC06**

Angular 7

I have a pretty typical use case:

1. Get list of available options from backend (wrapper.hydratedLeague.seasons)
2. Get list of selected options (wrapper.myseasons)
3. Present Angular Material multi-select dialog, defaulted with the appropriate options pre-selected

Implementation:

```
{{ logger.debug('wrapper.myseasons: ', wrapper.myseasons) }} // See log output below
{{ seasonsFormControl.setValue(wrapper.myseasons) }}         // (A) This will break <mat-option> appearance/behavior
{{ seasonsFormControl.setValue([2012526, 673768]) }}         // (B) This will not

<mat-select [formControl]="seasonsFormControl" (selectionChange)="omitted-not relevant" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let season of wrapper.hydratedLeague.seasons" [value]="season.key">
        {{season.value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Problem:

- If I *don't* set the value of seasonsFormControl at all, then the `<mat-select>` control cannot show the already-selected options (which is expected).  However, when I select options, the control behaves as expected, including the correct animations of `<mat-option>` . e.g. The checkbox shows selected and when I close/open the control, the options that I have selected in this interaction show selected
- If I set the value of seasonsFormControl using the `wrapper.myseasons` variable, then the `<mat-select>` control shows the correct selected options.  However, when I open the control to display the `<mat-option>` elements, none are shown as selected.  Also, if I select options, the standard animations do not take place and the checkbox is not checked.
- Just for illustration purposes, if I set the value of seasonsFormControl using an array of two integers, being the exact content of the earlier `wrapper.myseasons` variable, then everything behaves exactly as expected.  Defaults are shown properly in `<mat-select>` and `<mat-option>` elements show up as checked and render properly.

In both cases, the selectionChange event correctly detects and processes the selected options.

It seems as if the act of setting the FormControl value breaks (or at least changes) the UX behavior of the mat-option elements, which is a problem, because the end user can't see what they've selected already.

Am I making a rookie mistake?

**EDIT: 2019DEC06**

Thank you to those who have answered so far.  You have prodded me to refine the root cause of this problem, which I still don't understand and need help with.

I've edited the above example to more clearly illustrate the problem.

As you can see in the above edited code fragment, I have logged out the contents of `wrapper.myseasons`.  This is what I see (a copy / paste from the Chrome debug console):

```
wrapper.myseasons:  (2) [2012526, 673768]
0: 2012526
1: 673768
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here's how that `wrapper` object is declared:

```
export interface ILeagueWrapper {
    league?: number;
    hydratedLeague?: League;
    myrefereekey?: number;
    myseasons?: [number];
}

export class LeagueWrapper {
    private state: ILeagueWrapper = {};
    private internalHydratedLeague: League = null;

    get hydratedLeague(): League {
        return this.internalHydratedLeague;
    }

    set hydratedLeague(value: League) {
        this.internalHydratedLeague = value;
    }

    get league() {
        return this.state.league;
    }

    get myrefereekey() {
        return this.state.myrefereekey;
    }

    get myseasons() {
        return this.state.myseasons;
    }

}
```

As far as I can tell, in this example, (A) `wrapper.myseasons` is an array of two integers, identical to the hard-coded (B) equivalent.

Yet, (A) breaks `<mat-option>` but (B) works as expected.

It seems that `wrapper.myseasons` is somehow not being recognized as an array of integers and is breaking `<mat-option>` as a result.

I am sure this will turn out to be me not understanding something about TypeScript.  Could someone please educate me?

Thanks

Comment: Is your selected options in step 2 consists of only the keys and nothing else? If they are objects it might not work correctly.

Comment: wrapper.myseasons is a list of ints.  wrapper.hydratedLeague.seasons is a list of objects, containing key/value pairs (int/string).  so season.key is an int and season.value is a string.

Comment: Can't really reproduce, as shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4p1he

Comment: Can you show us your whole typescript and html code? Then we are maybe able to help you and find a solution.

Comment: please show more of the TS code. The loading of the data sets, the building of the form, the value setting and so on, both the version that works and the version that fails